# Why SingleThreadExecutor throws OutOfMemoryError in Java

Tags: multithreading, rabbitmq, threadpool, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I have a Message Producer (RabbitMq) and a springboot service that receives messages from this a Queue (RabbitMQ). S the amount of messages from this Queue is unknown as it depends on the traffic or amount of messages pushed to this rabbitMQ. After messages have been received from this RabbitMq into my Springboot service, I then store those messages locally in an ArrayDeque. Every message that comes through is stored in this local queue and then send to the socket to another Application. These messages have to be send in the order that they arrived from the RabbitMQ.

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
public void addMessageToQueue(CML cml) throws ParseException {

        if (cml != null) {
            AgentEventData agentEventData = setAgentEventData(cml);
            log.info("Populated AgentEventData: {} ", agentEventData);
            MessageProcessor.getMessageQueue().getMessageQueue().add(agentEventData);
//            ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MessageProcessor.getMessageQueue().getMessageQueue().size());
            log.info("Message QUEUE Size: {}", MessageProcessor.getMessageQueue().getMessageQueue().size());
            QUEUE_MONITOR.setCachedQueue(MessageProcessor.getMessageQueue());
            /**
             * Queue has already methods for monitoring events, no need for a seperate object
             * */

            executeTasks();

        } else {
            log.error("CML Message is NULL, Message Cannot be added to the Message Queue.");
        }
    }

    private static void executeTasks() {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        try {
            executorService.execute(new MessageProcessor());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception when executing Task: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
        log.info("Shutting down Executor Service........");
        executorService.shutdown();
        log.info("Executor Service Shutdown : {}", executorService.isShutdown());
    }
```

I tried using a newSingleThreadExecutor as shown in the executeTasks() method but after some time when my app is running in the server, i get the Consumer thread error, java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, unable to create native thread. Possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached.

I then tried newFixedThreadExecutor(10), and still get the same error after some time.

What is it that i am doing wrong and which approach best fit my App/Service ?

Comment: We are also facing the same issue. Nothing found much on this issue.

Comment: Your code is a bit odd. MessageProcessor contains a Queue as a static member, but you add to that queue and then call code that creates a MessageProcessor.

Are you trying to do too much in the same class? Maybe processing should be separate than the queue.

I don't have enough info here to see it. But you could be having some infinite recursion that is clogging up all available threads.